# ClassNotFoundException after updating to SoapUI 5.2.0

Tags: soapui

After having updated to SoapUI 5.2.0 I'm getting

```
15:58:00,756 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:127)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:406)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:363)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:368)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when I start "Launch TestRunner".
It seems that SoapUI 5.2.0 has some problems by loading some plugins.

Any idea what that could be?

Thx

Comment: Is this on startup, opening a project, or running a test?

Comment: Same here since a few hours. I am pretty sure everything worked yesterday.

Comment: This happens when I run the TestSuite with "Launch TestRunner"

Comment: Did you try this: http://www.soapui.org/support/support-overview.html

Comment: After some digging I understand why it happens, but I still do not have a solution.

Anyway the following is happening. It tries to load the class AutoImportMethodFactory, because there is a class PluginImportMethod (with annotation @AutoFactory) in the com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto package. In the code it translates "PluginImportMethod" to "AutoImportMethodFactory". 

The big question still remains: why did it work before?

Answer (score 39):

I did run into same issue with Soap-Ui 5.2 (OpenSource, 64b, Windows) version. When using Testrunner, it gave the same error. 
I noticed that 5.2 has these new plugins added and they are installed to your profile folder, under `c:\user\*YourUserName*\.soapuios\plugins`. This folder holds these jar files:  soapui-swagger-plugin-2.1.3-dist, ready-uxm-plugin-1.0.1-dist and ready-mqtt-plugin-dist.

Well, in my current project I have no use for those plugins so I just **re-named the .soapuions folder to NOT.soapuios**.

Then I re-launched testrunner from SoapUi and voila, there was no `AutoImportMethodFactory` error.

Ok, I am not sure if those plugins are the root cause but I think that it's not really a good idea that these kind of plugins are stored in windows User Profile -folder. eg. in Windows Server environment you have like 100 issues that can go wrong with that kind of setup :-)

Anyway, if someone knows how to rebase that plugins folder (I'd like to move it to same folder where Soapui is installed), I mean that is there a setting somewhere inside soapui that defines this folder, I would really appreciate that :-)

EDIT:

Just checked from 5.2 Release Notes *(#### Released 2015-07-02 ####)* from github and there is a bugfix mentioned:
* SoapUI failed to load plugins when you run tests with testrunner.bat and the current directory differed from `<SoapUI>\bin`.

Comment: That's a temporary "solution".... we want to use the new swagger plugin and would be nice to have things working fine... thx for the help

Comment: How about copying those plugin jar files to bin\ext -folder in your soap-ui installation folder? I did that and like other jar -files in my ext -folder, all were loaded without any error. Ok, I am not using the swagger -plugin and not sure how it's supposed to be used but have you tried that?

Comment: I tried that... and got no more exception. I was also able to Import a swagger.json file. Everything seems to work as expected. Thx Mikko

Comment: Really sorry, could not get it quite right in order to over come this error while requiring to use `swagger plugin`. Can any of you clarify? Appreciate your help.

Comment: In my case, SoapUI has probably installed the `.soapuios` folder to the wrong place. Most applications install these kind of files to `C:\Users\username` but I found it on my network profile (`H:\.soapuios` on my work machine)

Answer (score 4):

I get same issue with Windows 5.2.1 x64 version. I tried copying the files from c:\user*YourUserName*.soapuios\plugins to /bin/ext but that did not fix it for me. I renamed the c:\user*YourUserName*.soapuios\plugins folder to c:\user*YourUserName*.soapuios\plugins.backup (so SOAP UI could not find it), restarted SUI, and now I don't get these errors. I presume I don't have access to the plugins, but I am not using those at the moment anyway.

I am not running under a Windows Administrator account, that could be relevant here.

Comment: That's the best solution for me too for SoapUI 5.3.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same issue and I also wanted to use swagger plugin. It got resolved when I ran the soapui with administrator access, so I think it has to do something to do with accessing and executing the required JAR files to load plugins.

Answer (score -2):

**You can resolve your issue** (for any version of SoapUI listed above) ***by just renaming the original folder ‘plugins‘ to ‘plugins_NOTUsed‘ (or any other name of your choice)***. You might be thinking, by just renaming this folder how the actual problem has been solved – To explain this, it is just so that default plugins could be forced to be hidden during runtime and hence the problem doesn’t arise anymore.

Comment: This temporary workaround was also featured on the smartbear (pun intended) forum [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Feature-Requests/Resolving-quot-An-error-occurred-com-eviware-soapui-plugins-auto/idi-p/135281) but it does not solve the issue.