# Running soapui tests from testrunner.bat

Tags: soapui

I'm attempting to run `testrunner.bat` during our build process, but execution just hangs. When I logged on to the server with a different account and tried running it manually I noticed it started a popup asking about usage data, so I assume this is what is happening during the automated build. How can I turn this off for the build account that I can't logon with? Is there a computer wide setting of some sort?

Updated info:
I have already set disable usage statistics in preferences.
This is the output I get when I run `testrunner.bat` from my build process using a service account:

```
07:40:29,362 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at             [C:\Users\tfsservice\soapui-settings.xml]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further  details.
07:40:40,945 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 1 ms
07:40:40,946 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
```

If I logon to the server and run it manually using an admin account I get the following output instead (errors):

```
2016-04-20 08:00:38,340 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:38,380 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:38,576 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:38,596 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:40,433 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:40,463 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:41,553 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-20 08:00:41,591 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Running it locally on my machine works fine.

Comment: surely the problem in the automatic build is the popup. Where this popup comes from? any groovy script or so? if its the case share your code in order that we can check it to provide an alternative to avoid the popup `:)`.

Comment: The popup is the soapui "usage and statistics" question you get the first time you launch soapui, ie if you want to send them anonymous statistics. I can't logon to the server with the same account used by my build process so I can't figure out how to disable this.

Comment: ooops.. I think at first that this popup comes from another place... It's strange since the *usage and statistics* is not related to the project, instead comes from your preferences. I think that `testrunner.bat` not force this popup, so my guess is that this concret popup is not causing your issue. Anyway you can try to disable the *usage and statitic*, go to `File > Preferences` and there select `UI Settings` and mark the checkbox `Do not send usage statistics`

Comment: @albciff, you are right. May be that can be added as answer.

Comment: @Rao thanks `:)`, however I'm not sure that this is really causing the issue. I will wait for OP confirmation.

Comment: I have updated the original post with some more info

Comment: @iprotocol probably there are some problems loading the jars from the `USER_HOME/.soapuios` in your server, related to the permissions. Seems related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31409653/1218618), take a look `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the hanging was due to the usage statistics like I thought. I was forced to launch soapui on the server with "run as" using the service account and disable it under preferences, trying to disable it under the admin account didn't help.

I moved all the plugins from the user directory from which I installed soapui to the bin\ext folder like suggested to get rid of the plugin errors but I'm still getting them, so I've pretty much given up on that, the tests run though.