# SoapUI mock service deployment in Tomcat throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: tomcat, soapui, war, classnotfoundexception

I created a REST project on SoapUI 5.2.1. I deployed it to WAR, and my team deployed it to Tomcat. When I try to run it on Tomcat, it does not display anything.

I got an error log:

```
ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)

at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:94)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Still you should be able to hit your service, I believe. Isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException after updating to SoapUI 5.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409653/classnotfoundexception-after-updating-to-soapui-5-2-0)